# How to link my radio button to send thru email in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my send button to pop up and make me choose the branch that I want to email then send/submit. I am using Wordpress and I am not sure how to program that feature.

This is what I have so far:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding: 20px 0;">
        <ul>
            <li><label><input name="" value="mandaue" type="radio"> Mandaue</label></li>
            <li><label><input name="" value="mactan1" type="radio"> Mactan 1</label></li>
            <li><label><input name="" value="unread" type="radio"> Consolacion</label></li>
            <li><label><input name="" value="xml" type="radio"> Labangon</label></li>
            <li><label><input name="" value="csv" type="radio"> Guadalupe</label></li>
            <li><label><input name="" value="csv" type="radio"> Mactan2</label></li>
            <a href="#" class="contact-us-btn">Send</a>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you'll need a bit of Javascript here, block sending of form, display/uncover radio button group and after checking radio button submit the form

Comment: Sir @moped , sorry but can you detailed your explanation? I am newbie here, sorry.

Comment: show us full form code, in fiddle for example.. btw, isn't it better to use select box instead of radio ?